# PHP regex(PCRE) password check

Tags: php, regex

I came across the someone's password validate code, I tried to understand this regex but I cannot.

```
/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}/
```

I especially don't get the part

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

`(?=)` what is this for and why are there 3 groups of them prior to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)